# Is there a difference in usage between "le livre" and "le bouquin"?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

I have heard both words used to refer to a book. [Some](https://www.italki.com/question/279523) sources in the internet say there is no difference.

My experience from listening to French language is that perhaps "*le bouquin*" is a more informal word used to refer to modern books. For instance, I have heard [Olivier Roland](https://www.youtube.com/user/DesLivresPourChanger) use the word "*bouquin*" to refer to a book he wrote or to a book he recently read. On the other hand, during première/deuxième lecture in a church it is always "*lecture du livre de...*".

Is there a difference in the usage of both words? Would one of these words be used more often in a specific region/country?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your experience is right. ***Bouquin*** (from the Middle Dutch *[boec](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boec#Middle_Dutch)*) is nowadays an informal only way to refer to a book.

***Bouquin*** also often carries an emotional charge, either positive or negative while ***livre*** is neutral.